# Continuous onto image implies Continuous onto whole space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X \to Y$ such that $f: X \to f(X)$ is continuous as a mapping when $f(X)$ is endowed with the subspace topology inherited from $Y$. Is it also true that $f$ is continuous as a map $f:X \to Y$? Indeed for any open set $U \subset Y$ we have that $f^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(U \cap f(X))$ and the right hand side is open by assumption of continuity of $f: X \to f(X)$.

I can't think of any case where this is not true but just checking. Ty!

Comment: The map $X\to Y$ is the composition of the map $X\to f(X)$ and the inclusion $f(X)\to Y$. So it is a composition of two continuous functions, hence continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $i:f(X)\rightarrow Y$ be the inclusion. It is easily to be checked continuous.  Now $i\circ f$ is continuous as the composition of continuous maps is continuous.